# GORM: upsert not inserting proper values

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I am trying to find a way to UPSERT some values but I got some unexpected behavior. For example:

```
db.Clauses(clause.OnConflict{
    Columns:   []clause.Column{{Name: "name"}},
    DoUpdates: clause.AssignmentColumns([]string{"name", "email"}),
})
```

Returns

`ON CONFLICT (name) DO UPDATE SET name = {excluded name %!s(bool=false)}, email = {excluded email %!s(bool=false)} RETURNING *`

, which doesn't seems right.

I also tried building a map of names and expressions:

`values := map[email:excluded.email name:excluded.name col3:table.col3+excluded.col3]`

```
db.Clauses(clause.OnConflict{
    Columns:   []clause.Column{{Name: "name"}},
    DoUpdates: clause.Assignments(values),
})
```

Which generates

`DO UPDATE SET "email"='excluded.email',"name"='excluded.name'`

but I expect

`DO UPDATE SET "email"="excluded.email","name"="excluded.name"`

Gorm version: v1.20.6

Golang version: 1.12

Postgres 12

Comment: The newer versions of Gorm have some issues with Go versions below 1.13. Go is at 1.15 now, try upgrading to that. Maybe it won't help with your specific issue but it's still better to be on a Go version upwards of 12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just ran into a similar issue where GORM wasn't updating the data of an associated table when upserting a model referencing this association (ex: upsert on a `user` table with an associated `bill` model where the `bill` data has changed and was expected to be save along the `user`'s save).

It turns out GORM only updates fields that are making the association / foreign key, not the actual data. You need to turn on `FullSaveAssociations` session option in order to update all the fields. (see https://gorm.io/docs/session.html#FullSaveAssociations and https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/3506)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Saved me a lot of headache